# Dropdown value is not getting save in ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have saved the dropdown value in db and in the viewstate, but on page load it is not getting loaded. 
Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
if (ViewState["ddSelectedValue"] != "0")
        {
            dd_RuleFor.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ddSelectedValue"]).ToString();
        }
}

protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     if(chkRuleApprover.Checked == true && dd_RuleFor.SelectedValue != "0")
        {

            strSQL = "update UserFile  set Rule_Approval_Selection=" + dd_RuleFor.SelectedItem.Value  + " where UID=" + intUserID;
            objCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, oconn);
            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            ViewState["ddSelectedValue"] = dd_RuleFor.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
}
```

Comment: can you share your hardcode binding value code?

Comment: Wy are you using your own `ViewState` to save the `SelectedValue`? Normally asp.net ViewState will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are filling the dropdown with the values first on pageload and after than use below condition:

```
if(!Page.Ispostback())
{
if (ViewState["ddSelectedValue"] != "0")
    {
        dd_RuleFor.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ddSelectedValue"]).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I have filled the dd values by hardcoding it in the aspx

Comment: good then you have to use the above page.Ispostback() condition ,can you please post the both design page+ code page. Also , have you used update panel?

Comment: Also, you don't have to convert the view state value into int32 and then again back to string. avoid boxing -unboxing